# "xxx is foolish" and "xxx is being foolish"

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-continuous

> [Tom Brady is being foolish for practicing during the pandemic.](https://sports.yahoo.com/emmanuel-acho-tom-brady-being-204919147.html)

In my understanding, the commentator implies, **by using present continuous tense**, that Tom Brady's foolishness is just temporary. If this is correct, would it add a little insulting implication if the commentator said "Tom Brady **is foolish** for practicing during the pandemic."? Or does that make no difference?

Comment: I don't hear any difference in that context.

Comment: Is that because the commentary includes the phrase "during the pandemic"?

Comment: Yes, and more, "foolish for practicing during the pandemic". That details the entire argument as to why foolishness is attributed. If you were comparing "is being foolish for doing X" and a flat "is foolish", there would be a difference. But different people will hear it differently. Even if such a shade of meaning is found there, was the speaker being careful enough to observe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that **xxx is foolish** differentiates from **xxx is being foolish** in potential for the first to be considered a *value judgment*.

Stating someone *is foolish* with no other qualifiers and no other context is a fairly direct statement. Left with no other context we are made to assume that this is *how this person is*. With no reference to time, we understand that it applies at all times.

Stating someone *is **being** foolish* leaves room to interpret that while xxx is engaged in something foolish, it is temporary, because you've given the context of a specific time frame. This can give the reader the understanding that the foolishness is confined to that moment being described. We can still deem xxx to be *foolish in general*, but also that it could just be xxx did something foolish at a time and then continued their life of non-foolish behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, Evan. Does that mean it makes no difference, in my example, by saying either "is foolish" or "is being foolish" because the commentary includes a qualifier "during the pandemic"?

Comment: "during the pandemic" gives us context as to _why_ someone thinks what they think about xxx. That context helps me understand why someone thinks xxx is foolish, otherwise I might question why you would make the judgment that someone **is foolish**.

The "is foolish" or "is being foolish" portion can be taken on its own, and makes a difference in whether you are saying someone can be described as a _foolish person_ (i.e. a judgment) or has simply _done something foolish_ (less judgmental tone; we all do foolish stuff sometimes).